# What are the best places to invade hosts and get a kill?

Tags: dark-souls-2

Using cracked red orbs, I would like to know where are the best places to invade hosts and manage to get a kill eventually using monsters and traps to get tokens of spite.

I am not very good at duelling but would like to practice so I need to get a kill to join the brotherhood covenant.

Comment: If you just need a Token of Spite to join the covenant, there is one in a chest at the bottom of the pit in Majula.

Comment: hahaha, I did wonder the same, but then I invade someone in Lost Bastille and when he's fighting a dog, I drain the blood out of him and the lady got her token of spite.

Comment: I am really bad at this, I keep falling into lava, holes and it seems people always lag so badly I kept getting backstabbed when the guy is in front of me in the screen. It looks like for PvP you need to learn the dash or rolling + attacks and timing to beat the lag. Rolling is almost OP, also it is extremely hard to hunt someone who is dashing away to heal.

Comment: If someone is able to go away and heal in time, it obviously is because of your build. You are the one that needs to adapt.
Still, before the executioner chariot could be great place to invade someone, since it's a pretty difficult and stressful part, try there

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what lvl are you, but I would suggest to choose an area that you passed recently. And now, some places where (IMHO) invading is easier:

1. Iron keep - Iron Hearth Hall: take the small door on the left, kill the Alonne captain and then kill the the two Ironclad on the bridge. Keep going until the large lava room and clear the Alonne archer on the right. If you invade here, you can use platforms and / or fire to help you.
2. Drangleic Castle - King's Gate: once out the bonefire room, take the first on the right (the room full of sentilens "sleeping"). You can invade here, but do not cross the door on the right or you will invade the area before the next boss.
3. Black Gulch - Black Gulch Mouth or Hidden Chamber: if you use fire you can set the oil (I guess) on fire (but possibly after the mob came out), use poisoning statues to trap him or other mobs;
4. Sinner's Rise - The Saltfort: take stairs on the right, than kill the 4 undeads and take the elevator. Once down you can start invading.

I don't know what is your build, but I have few tips if you have trouble invading.

1. Keep the Black Separation Crystal and be ready to use it if the situation get bad. He can heal, but you can leave his world;
2. You can invade for 10 minutes, even if he summons others to help him you can still hide somewhere and use the environment or other mobs;
3. Don't just focus on one build: be ready to go close combat and try a back-stab or a shield-break if the situation require it, but also be ready to have an alternative to melee combat and remember that your spells cannot hit other mobs;
4. Find your own style (or copy it from an opponent you like);
5. Play with distance: stay close enough to prevent him from healing, but far enough to prevent being hit;
6. Understand his style and play against him. For example: some just wait you to hit to counter-attack and finish you in one hit (usually armed with a parry knife or a small shield on the left and a big weapon on the right), others just aim to finish you with spells, and so on.

Good luck! ;)